# Word/phrase for "non-stick figures"

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

I am looking for a word or a term for "non-stick figures": For example at
https://www.giantitp.com/comics/oots0339.html
you can see stick figures and in the last row of the comic at the first box a "graphic graphic". Neither "non-stick figure" nor "graphic graphic" nor "graphic figure" sticks with me. Both types are graphics (paintings, drawings,...), but the non-stick ones are - what? Realistic, naturalistic,... graphics of persons?

Comment: I thought you meant 'non-stick' as in saucepans at first! I think a 'figure drawing' or 'cartoon figure' would be assumed not to be a stick figure unless that was specified.

Comment: Sticks figures and other depictions. Otherwise, I have no idea what you mean. We wouldn't say non-stick figures....

Comment: See [What is the Difference Between 3D and 2D Animation?](https://www.dbswebsite.com/blog/what-is-the-difference-between-3d-and-2d-animation/)

Comment: Fully rendered? Photorealistic? See Wikipedia on *Rendering*, for example.

Comment: I’m closing this question because it's requesting a technical art term, which is outside the scope of ELL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have chosen "naturalistic drawing".